# Svelte - Transitions in layout not delaying {#key}ed <slot> update

Tags: animation, svelte, sveltekit

I'm trying to add a transition between pages in a SvelteKit application. When navigating, the current page should fade out, and the new page should then fade in in its place. To accomplish this, in `+layout.svelte`, I wrapped the `<slot>` in a `div` with the in and out transitions set. I wrapped this all in `{#key $page.url.pathname}` so that the animations are triggered when navigating from page to page. However, my current code produces this effect:

[image: An animated gif of the problem]

When navigating, the content of the page updates *before* fading out. In other words, the destination page immediately appears, then fades out, then fades back in. At the same time, though, content in `+layout.svelte` (`.title`, at the top of the page) behaves correctly; just the content within the `<slot>` is bugged.

Here is the code:

**+layout.svelte**

```
<script lang="ts">
    import '$lib/style.css';

    import { page } from '$app/stores';
    import { fade } from 'svelte/transition';
</script>

<div class="page">
    <div class="bar">
        Sidebar
        <a href="/">Page 1</a>
        <a href="/page2">Page 2</a>
    </div>

    <div class="content-wrapper">
        {#key $page.url.pathname}
            <div class="content" in:fade={{ delay: 1000, duration: 1000 }} out:fade={{ duration: 1000 }}>
                <div class="title">
                    {$page.url.pathname}
                </div>

                <slot />
            </div>
        {/key}
    </div>
</div>

<style global>
    .page {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row;

        box-sizing: border-box;
        width: 100vw;
        min-height: 100vh;
    }

    .bar {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;

        width: 300px;

        color: white;
        background: black;
    }

    a {
        color: white;
    }

    .content-wrapper {
        flex-grow: 1;

        width: 100%;
        min-height: 100vh;
    }

    .content {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
    }

    .title {
        font-size: 2em;
    }
</style>
```

**+page.svelte**

```
<div class="page">
    <div class="title">Page 1</div>
</div>

<style>
    .page {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;

        background: blue;
    }
</style>
```

**page2/+page.svelte**

```
<div class="page">
    <div class="title">Page 2</div>
</div>

<style>
    .page {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;

        background: red;
    }
</style>
```

Is there a way to get the `<slot>` content to wait for the out animation to finish before updating?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using the `$page` store, the slot content seems to be updated correctly when moving the logic to the `layout.js` load function.

[REPL](https://www.sveltelab.dev/0hdeed8t56im9e0)

###### +layout.js

```js
export const load = ({ url }) => {
  const { pathname } = url

  return {
    pathname
  }
}
```

###### +layout.svelte

```
<script>
    import { fly } from 'svelte/transition';

    export let data;

</script>

{#key data.pathname}
    <div
        class="transition-wrapper"
        in:fly={{ x: 100, duration: inDuration, delay: outDuration }}
        out:fly={{ x: -100, duration: outDuration }}
    >
        <slot />
    </div>
{/key}
```

Answer (score 1):

Its an issue with the lifecycle of the transitions for in and out.
I usually use in:fade ONLY on elements and it looks okay. It seems using both means that while one element is going out, another is coming in at the same time in which looks funny.

Perhaps you could find out more about delay in transitions and let us know..
Happy coding☺️

Comment: Thanks, I'll use this for now until I can find a fix